# Windows "disallowed" icon appears when dragging element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a fairly simple slider using jQuery. To do this i am using the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events.

```
var pageX;
$handle.bind('mousedown',function(a){
    pageX = a.pageX;
    $handle.bind('mousemove',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = pageX - e.pageX;
        pageX = e.pageX;

        var left = $handle.position().left;
        $handle.css({left:(left-delta)+'px'});
    });
});
        $handle.bind('mouseup',function(){
            $handle.unbind('mousemove');
        });
```

Now, this actually works great, except for that when i drag the handle to fast, the "block" icon appears (you know, the circle with a cross over it). How can i prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix it by preventing default behavior of the `mousedown` event

```
$handle.bind('mousedown', function(a) {
    a.preventDefault()
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually set the cursor to anything: http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm

In this example you would use:

```
.css('cursor','default');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue, i still get the block-icon that prevents me from keep dragging the element.

Comment: Can you post a demo / example ?

Comment: http://sodemo.appload.nu/slider/

As you can see, when you drag the slider too fast, the browser seems to block it somehow...

Comment: This is because once you hover away from the box, the dragging stop's, you need to direct click, so while mousedown and dragging, ajust the slider, and only stop ajusing it when mouseup, like in this example: http://jqueryui.com/slider/ .

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. What should i change? The box is already moving with the cursor, but when that is done to fast, the cursor probably gets out of the box causing this behaviour.

Comment: He means that you are sliding using the 'hover' event. Use the mousedown/mouseup events instead. This will probably fix your issue, as well as be a better user experience.

Comment: I am indeed using the mousedown/mouseup events.